# working with simple illustrator shapes in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, adobe-illustrator

In my app, there are some shapes that the user can drag around the screen and stretch both vertically and horizontally. These shapes are simple shapes that I'm drawing in illustrator, ie an ellipse, a star shape, a cloud.

I'm wondering:

1) How should I go about implementing these in my app? Is it better to import the file and instantiate it in an imageview? Or should I try to draw these shapes in drawRect on some view?

2) If it is better to draw the shape in core graphics, how is it possible for me to get the data from the illustrator file so that I can draw it easily in CoreGraphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if it's possible, you should try to draw the shape in core graphics as its better for memory and becomes resolution independent. I found a program called for $40 on the OSX app store that converts SVG files to iOS / OSX code. It's called [Qwarkee](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qwarkee/id498340809?mt=12).